# Data not inserted from XML file in ADF if nested array only has one value

Tags: xml, azure-data-factory

I have a task where i will be inserting several XML-files into a table.

I have managed to set up a pipeline in ADF that works fine. But now i have discovered that few of the files are not inserted. They are not failing, they are just not inserted.

This is my mapping:
[image]

I have now realized that the files that are not inserting any data only has one item in OrdinaryCargo whish is used as Collectionreference. In most of the files there are 2 or more OrdinaryCargo.

Here is an example from a "normal" file. This one works

[image]

This file does NOT work

[image]

Other than having different amounts of OrdinaryCargo, the files are exactly the same structure.

My question is how can i insert data from files that only have one OrdinaryCargo, can i still use the approach with Collection reference or do i need to do it differently?
Is there a way that i can check the content in the file first and then choose a different way to flatten the data depending on the number of OrdinaryCargos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Single row in the XML gets converted to an object instead of an array. This can be problematic when you give the array element in the collection reference as a generalized pipeline. The better approach to solve this is to bifurcate them and give two copy activity - one with source xml having arrays and other without array (single row).

- In order to bifurcate, take the lookup activity and then take the xml dataset in that.
- Then take the set variable activity and convert the result of the lookup activity to string.

```
@string(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].PortCall.MessageList.CargoList.OrdinoCargo.OC_TransportUnit)
```

[image]

- Then take the if condition activity, and give the expression as `@startswith(variables('<variable-name>'),'[')`. This checks if the result string starts with `[`. If it is true, then source XML has array of elements. If it is false, then it has single object.
- Give two different copy activities - One for true case and other for false case with different mappings for both case.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what i was looking for! I got an error message in set variable: The expression cannot be evaluated because property 'value' doesn't exist. Do you know why this is? Did i miss something in my lookup, i just put my xml as source dataset and nothing else.

Comment: I guess, you have selected `first row only` in your lookup activity. If yes, Can you uncheck that.

Comment: Yes that was it! It works fine now when im testing with and without array in the file. It works when i only have one file. What´s left now is that i need to do this for all my 900 files. In my lookup i have a wildcard file path to take all *.xml files and i have chosen Recursively, but do i need to create a foreach loop or something to get all my files into the if statement and forward?

Comment: How was your approach previously? Is it like for-each-> copy activity?

Comment: In my first solution when i didnt have the if statements i just had a copy data activity with Wildcard file path, that way it took all the files in the container and inserted them. But in this new solution only the first file is selected in the lookup and then passed forward.

Comment: Okay. The approach should be like 1. Lookup/get Metadata activity (to get the list of xml file names) 2. For-each activity (input for foreach activity will be the lookup activity) Inside for-each activity, you can give this approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257218/discussion-between-aswin-and-glaring).